# how to show data like grid view in ipad application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, datagrid

Is there any way to show data in the grid view form in ipad application

I want to show the data in grid view in ipad application i have searched a lot some say use custom table view but it is not looking i want full professional i found iOS DataGrid TableView for ipad.

Is it ok to use wether it is free or not. And how to implement this if it possible or not.
Below is the link of iOS Grid

http://www.binpress.com/app/ios-data-grid-table-view/586

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can you not have stumbled upon [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView/).

However if you are just interested in styling a cell only, you can implement a [custom uitableview cell](http://kshitizghimire.com.np/create-custom-uitableviewcell/) which has few grids  and style them according to your requirement.

There are many tutorials out there showing how to customize a `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 1):

Create custom UITableViewCell as per your requirement and load that cell to table view cell.

You can use below sample code to load custom cell with in table's cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *sCellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:sCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObject = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: @"CustomCell"  owner:self options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObject) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = (CustomCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    cell.label1.text = @"label1"; // you can access all controllers of your custom cell like this way   
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By Using the CustomUITableViewCell you can get the same.i.e Take the UITableviewcell and add the three or four labels to it.Then Pass the data in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 0):

I used GMGridview, it has an example and basically if you change the cell size, and columns you can make it fit in iPad or iPhone. You can also add UITextField (instead of the default UILabel), if you need to input data. One nice feature is it can scroll.

http://www.gmoledina.ca/projects/gmgridview/

Feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: Came across this MDSpreadView today. I have not looked deep into it, but it appears pretty cool. https://github.com/mochidev/MDSpreadView

Answer (score 0):

We use this one in our application : http://www.ioscomponents.com/. We like it so far.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning our product!! We have opensourced it! https://github.com/flexicious/iOSDataGrid